# What good are the signs '-' (minus) in any Linux/UNIX commands?

Tags: linux, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “--” (double-dash) mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)
>   [Single dashes `-` for single-character options, but double dashes `--` for words?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words)

I was reading the man zip page and I found this examples:

[...] using the command

**unzip -p backup | tar xf -**

When [...]  For example,

**tar cf - . | zip | dd of=/dev/nrst0 obs=16k**

is equivalent to

**tar cf - . | zip - - | dd of=/dev/nrst0 obs=16k**

I' like know the minus utility of these cases. Why two minus signs are written in the third case?

Comment: See: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words

Comment: @jasonwryan That one doesn't seem related. This looks like a combination of [Usage of dash (-) in place of a filename](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename) and [What does "--" (double-dash) mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean) though; I think I'm going with the latter since that's the actual question at the end

Comment: Thanks both @jasonwryan and Michael. I found Michael's answer helpful

Comment: There's no `--` in this question.  It`s `- -`, meaning create the ZIP file on standard output, and read the data to compress from standard input.  So I'm pretty sure it's http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16357/usage-of-dash-in-place-of-a-filename.