# Add sid field to ps -f output

Tags: linux, ps

I am reading the ps man page and there is something I don't understand.

```
-f    does full-format listing. This option can be combined with many other
      UNIX-style options to add additional columns. It also causes the
      command arguments to be printed. When used with -L, the NLWP (number of 
      threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be added. See the c option,
      the format keyword args, and the format keyword comm.
```

I just want to add `sid` to the output of `ps -f`

But I was confused by the following output, my understanding is `-o` should just add `sid` to the output of `-f` but looks like `-o` overwrites `-f` completely.

I know I can specify all the options I want, like `pid,ppid,pgid,sid,user,comm` etc etc but is there a way just add one additional column to output of `-f` ? That is what the man page says, correct ?

```
[njia@cst-cgxfile01 ~]$ ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
njia      3397 26106  0 12:23 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -f
njia     26106 26105  0 09:45 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
[njia@ ~]$ ps -f -o sid
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
  SID
26106
26106
25875
25875
25875
25875
25875
[njia@ ~]$
```

In addition, `ps -ef -o sid` will limit the process selection to those owned my me, that was a surprise as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question, there are several flags you can add to `-f`.  They include `-l`, `-j`, `-m`, and `-L`.  Unfortunately `-o <format>` can't be combined with `-f`.

Indeed, the best way to get exactly what you want, is to specify exactly what you want, e.g.

```
ps -e -o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,user,comm
```

But you can get *really* close by adding `-j` to `-f`, to make `ps -efj`.  This adds both the `PGID` and `SID` columns.

Demonstrating without the `-e` flag to make the output shorter, compare:

```
$ ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
myuser     123  4513  0 18:20 pts/26   00:00:00 zsh
myuser     1282  123  0 18:20 pts/26   00:00:00 ps -f

$ ps -fj
UID        PID  PPID  PGID   SID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
myuser     123  4513   123   123  0 18:20 pts/26   00:00:00 zsh
myuser     1402  123  1402   123  0 18:20 pts/26   00:00:00 ps -fj
```

---

To answer the second part of your question, the reason `ps -ef -o sid` only shows your own processes, is it switches to BSD mode when it decides your flags weren't POSIX compliant.  This is indicated by the message

```
Warning: bad syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See /usr/share/doc/procps-3.2.8/FAQ
```

So it's equivalent to running `ps ef o sid`.

In BSD mode, `e` means it will print the process's environment, and `f` means "forest".  And BSD mode defaults to printing all processes owned by the current user that have *any* terminal, not just those on the current terminal.

Try changing the `-o sid` to `-o sid,cmd` to see the effects of `e` and `f` options.

```
$ ps ef o sid
SID
12345
  567
  567
...

$ ps ef o sid,cmd
  SID CMD
12345 -zsh USER=... LOGNAME=...
  567 zsh PWD=... LANG=...
  567  \_ ps ef o sid,cmd LANG=... PWD=...
...
```

And compare to `ps u` to see that the processes shown are the same (I added `| wc -l` for brevity).

```
$ ps ef o cmd | wc -l
20
$ ps u | wc -l
20
```

Comment: I think you're absolutely right, I don't get this error message on my Debian though.

Comment: `ps -eO sid f` worked for me but that is even more wired. There are `-f` in output format control and `f` in output modifier. I can do this `ps -f f` and it gives me all the fields included by `ps -f` but in `ps f` format. This becomes more interesting.

Comment: `ps ef sid,cmd` gives me a syntax error, do you mean `ps ef o sid,cmd` ?

Comment: Note that this is not actually how BSD `ps` worked, and was documented, for the whole lifetime of procps `ps`.  The "BSD mode" nomenclature is an error perpetuated by the procps manual.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511530/5132

Answer (score 2):

Everything you state is correct, `ps` will only list processes owned by you unless you tell it otherwise with `x` or `a` or similar options. `-o` sets the format, it is not cumulative. So, to get the output of `ps -f` with `SID` added, you will need to specify the whole thing using `-o`:

```
$ ps -f 
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
terdon   27452 27436  0 02:48 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash
terdon   30622 27452  0 02:51 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -f
$ ps -o user,pid,sid,ppid,c,stime,tty,time,cmd
USER       PID   SID  PPID  C STIME TT           TIME CMD
terdon   27452 27452 27436  0 02:48 pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash
terdon   30905 27452 27452  0 02:51 pts/3    00:00:00 ps -o user,pid,sid,ppid,c,stime,tty,time,cmd
```

To get the same output for all users, use this:

```
ps -axo user,pid,sid,ppid,c,stime,tty,time,cmd
```

The closest you can get to adding to as opposed to overwriting the output format is  using `-O` (that's O as in Oliver, not `0`):

```
-O format
    Like -o, but preloaded with some default columns.  
    Identical to -o pid,format,state,tname,time,command or
                 -o pid,format,tname,time,cmd
```

So, for example:

```
$ ps -O sid
  PID   SID S TTY          TIME COMMAND
 4879 27452 R pts/3    00:00:00 ps -O sid
27452 27452 S pts/3    00:00:00 /bin/bash
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I am still confused by `ps -ef -O sid` only list processes owned by myself, what happened to `-e` option. Looks like ps just ignored it. It works if I do this `ps -eO sid f`.

Comment: @AskandLearn the `ps` man page is one of the most complex I've ever seen. I agree that the `-f` seems to be eating `-e` but have no idea why.

Comment: The `-f` isn't eating the `-e`.  The `-f` and the `-o` conflict, so `ps` tries to parse it in BSD mode instead.  And in BSD mode `-e` means something different.

Comment: @Mikel yes, I understood when I read your answer, thanks!