# Top-like command configurable from command line

Tags: ubuntu, top

For Ubuntu Bionic, is there a tool that will, like `top`, show various data on processes and refresh automatically, but can be configured from the command line to specify what data (columns) to show?

Comment: @msp9011 like, only show the `COMMAND` column, which should be specified on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

`procps` `top`, the one found on Ubuntu is probably the most configurable of `top` implementations.

To change the list of fields, press <kbd>f</kbd> and you can add remove  fields, change their orders, etc.

There is a lot more you can change there, including colour, layout, including multi-pane views, the header at the top...

You can save those configuration by pressing <kbd>W</kbd>.

That will go to `~/.toprc` (or `~/.config/procps/toprc` in newer versions).

You can save them as a different profile by calling `top` with a different name. For instance, if you make a `mytop` symlink to  the `top` executable, and invoke it, or run `top` as `(exec -a mytop top)`, then <kbd>W</kbd> will save the configuration to `~/.mytoprc` instead, so you can define a variety of differently flavoured versions of `top` that way.

Answer (score 0):

It's a dilemma, isn't it?

- `top` has automatic refresh, but no way to specify the columns to display.
- `ps` and its ilk can be told what columns to output, but do not continually update.

I am part of the way towards addressing this for myself.

I already have a tool that can take the data of a table input over a pipe, and display it full screen on a terminal in a scrollable columnar format.  It is the `console-flat-table-viewer` command from the nosh toolset.  Feed it at intervals on its standard input a succession of tables, delimited by the relevant *file separator* character, and it will provide a continually updated display.

Note that this *is not* like `watch`.  `watch` takes any old input.  `console-flat-table-viewer` expects its input to be *a table*, in one of the several well-known flat file encodings that one find on Unices and Linux operating systems, and its user interface presents it *as a table*, aligned into rows and columns and with headings and a cursor.

The other part of the mechanism is a tool that emits the process table in such a flat file form in the first place, repeatedly at intervals, interspersing its output with a *file separator*.  We almost, but do not quite, have this.

One can feed it the output of the `top` command in its "batch" mode:

```
while top -b all | sed -e '1,8s/^/#/' -e $'1i\\n\\f'
do
    sleep 1
done | 
console-flat-table-viewer --header-count 1
```

The `sed` turns into comments the part of the `top` output that is not actually the process table, which would otherwise confuse the table layout, and adds in the *file separator*.  In the table encoding that matches what `top` outputs, what the `console-flat-table-viewer` manual calls the `space` format, the file separator is the ␌ character, which has to be escaped for `sed` to not strip it.  (ASCII has a real ␜  character, which `console-flat-table-viewer` understands for `ascii` tables.  This is not the encoding that `top` outputs, though.)

I add the ␌ character with `sed` to reduce display flicker, so that `console-flat-table-viewer` does not receive it until immediately before the rest of the table data.  An alternative, which flickers slightly more because there is an interval between the ␌ and the table data during which `console-flat-table-viewer` displays a blank table, is to simply invoke `printf` first.

Similarly, the commands that generate the output go in the condition of the `while` loop, so that the broken pipe when I quit `console-flat-table-viewer` causes the loop to gracefully terminate.

But this does not provide control over columns.

One can alternatively feed it the output of the FreeBSD `procstat` command:

```
while printf '\f' ; procstat -a
do
    sleep 1
done | 
console-flat-table-viewer --header-count 1
```

This has a limited degree of control over columns with its various options, but not fine grained control.  It is also somewhat problematic because several of its options cause it to break the tabular format by emitting unescaped whitespace in the middle of fields.

One could use the BSD `ps` command:

```
while ps -a -x -o "pid,ppid,user,logname,time,state,wchan,start,comm" | sed -e $'1i\\n\\f'
do
    sleep 1
done |
console-flat-table-viewer --header-count 1
```

The GNU-licensed `ps` command on Ubuntu Linux has a different command-line syntax, which is several questions and answers in its own right, but one could employ it likewise.

Whilst this *does* have fine-grained control over the columns, it *again* does not properly escape whitespace within fields.

The BSDs have had a way of dealing with this since 4.4BSD in the 1990s.  It is the `vis()` encoding system, which various BSD flat tables (such as `/etc/fstab`) already employ.  `console-flat-table-viewer` already knows how to decode it, too.  It would be very welcome for `ps` or `procstat`, preferably both, to be able to `vis`-encode their outputs.

The obvious next step for GUI users is to have a (currently hypothetical) utility that substitutes for `console-flat-table-viewer`, taking the same input and leaving the input side of the pipeline the same, and displays continually updated tables with a GUI instead of a TUI.

Then we could have a flexible mechanism made of composable tools joined together with pipes.  ☺

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2019). [`console-flat-table-viewer`](http://jdebp.uk/Softwares/nosh/guide/commands/console-flat-table-viewer.xml).  *nosh Guide*.  Softwares.
- "[Roadmap](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd-quarterly/blob/master/2018q4/nosh.md#roadmap)". *The nosh project*.  FreeBSD Quarterly Status Update 2018Q4.
- Robert N M    Watson (2017-01-14). [procstat](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=procstat).  *FreeBSD General Commands Manual*.
- [ps](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=ps).  *FreeBSD General Commands Manual*. 2018-03-13.
- [vis](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=vis).  *FreeBSD General Commands Manual*. 2013-02-19.
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511530/5132