# Why does `ps -Af` display usernames in the "UID" column, while `ps -Ao uid` displays the numerical user IDs in that column?

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, ps

While I find the `-f` option to `ps` really useful, I miss the numerical UIDs in the output.

Using `ps -Ao uid` it's possible to display the numerical UIDs:

```
nlykkei@debian:/proc/1839/net$ ps -Af | head -n5
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 02:00 ?        00:00:09 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 17
root         2     0  0 02:00 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 02:00 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_gp]
root         4     2  0 02:00 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_par_gp]


nlykkei@debian:/proc/1839/net$ ps -Ao uid,user,pid,command | head -n5
  UID USER       PID COMMAND
    0 root         1 /lib/systemd/systemd --system --deserialize 17
    0 root         2 [kthreadd]
    0 root         3 [rcu_gp]
    0 root         4 [rcu_par_gp]
```

Is it possible to add the numerical UIDs to the output of `ps -Af`? I cannot use `ps -Af -o uid`, and I don't want to type all of the columns that the `-f` option provides manually?

Answer (score 2):

Since you’re using Debian, your [`ps`](https://manpages.debian.org/procps/ps.1) supports combined [so-called “BSD-style” and “Unix-style” options](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/78691/86440), you can use the `n` option which uses numbers for `WCHAN` and `USER`:

```
ps n -Af
```

Comment: thanks. Can you say what exactly "WCHAN" refers too?

Comment: For sleeping processes, it’s the kernel function inside which they’re sleeping. See the manpage for details.

Comment: That is not really a BSD option, of course.  It's what one `ps` command's manual erroneously describes as BSD options.  Actually, it's _that `ps`command's own_ idiosyncratic option. https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/511530/5132

Comment: @StephenKitt - why does the `n` take precedence over `-f`, when displaying the output? I'm just wondering why it makes the `UID` column display numerically? Furthermore, isn't it wrong for the `-f` option to name the column `UID`, when it displays usernames? There is a distinction between `-o uid` and `-o user`...

Comment: @StephenKitt - Also, I don't see any `WCHAN` in the output on Debian 9?