# Abbreviated long options on the command line of xclip

Tags: options, xclip

In the manpage of `xclip`

```
-selection

specify which X selection to use, options are 
"primary" to use XA_PRIMARY (default), 
"secondary" for XA_SECONDARY or 
"clipboard" for XA_CLIPBOARD

Note that only the first character of the selection specified with the -selection option is important. 
This means that "p", "sec" and  "clip"  would
have the same effect as using "primary", "secondary" or "clipboard" respectively.
```

The following for using clipboard selection works

```
    xclip -sel clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

the manpage says that `clipboard` can be shortened to `clip`, but doesn't say that `-selection` can be shortened to `-sel`.

So why does it work? Does this feature for specifying an option belong to `xclip`, or also to many other applications besides `xclip`?

Comment: Do you mean to ask a specific question about xclip/paste and a general option-shortening one in the same Q? The second seems independent -- and broad.

Answer (score 3):

`xclip` uses the X Toolkit library, which does the options-parsing.  All of the options can be abbreviated.  The library only gives an error if there is an ambiguity.

Options, of course, are things like `-select` which can be abbreviated as `-sel` (possibly even `-s`).

`xterm` uses the same library, same behavior.  It uses special cases (outside the library) to make the `-v` command a unique abbreviation for `-version`, etc.

X Toolkit uses a single dash `-` for options, and does not distinguish between "short" and "long" because it is not an extension of `getopt`.  As I pointed out in *[Single dashes `-` for single-character options, but double dashes `--` for words?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21852/single-dashes-for-single-character-options-but-double-dashes-for-words/271636#271636)*, it was introduced around the same time as GNU getopt, which *did* extend `getopt`.  This was before POSIX came along, but *`AT&T`* `getopt` had several years of use, establishing its role for single-character options.  GNU `getopt` uses a double-dash `--` to denote *long* options.

Noting a long digression, you can read the source code for GNU getopt (which is unrelated to `xclip`) from its [git repository](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=posix/getopt.c;h=88acff0e2f6f00e1508f151fab74717f95674bb8;hb=247fdc8ee68cf49cd808becce56b2e923b4f776b#l369), e.g.,

```
 369    Long-named options begin with `--' instead of `-'.
 370    Their names may be abbreviated as long as the abbreviation is unique
 371    or is an exact match for some defined option.  If they have an
 372    argument, it follows the option name in the same ARGV-element, separated
 373    from the option name by a `=', or else the in next ARGV-element.
 374    When `getopt' finds a long-named option, it returns 0 if that option's
 375    `flag' field is nonzero, the value of the option's `val' field
 376    if the `flag' field is zero.
```

Comment: thanks. does getopt library also allow shortening options in the same way as the X toolkit library?

Comment: [getopt](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) is a standard function that only knows about single-character options.  GNU [getopt_long](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt-Long-Options.html#Getopt-Long-Options) permits abbreviations of long options.

Comment: getopt_long only support single character abbreviation, does it?

Comment: `getopt_long` (like X Toolkit) allows any length.  But if two options match with a given length, that would produce a warning about ambiguous options.

Comment: The link you gave says "To accept GNU-style long options as well as single-character options, use getopt_long instead of getopt."  For example, it doesn't say that option `-select` can be shorten to be `-sel` but only to `-s`

Comment: I got that by running commands to test them.  You can also read the source code.  The documentation needs some work.

Comment: Is parsing arbitrary shortened option implemented in terms of regex matching?

Comment: Is it correct that -sel by shortening -select is still a long option, not a short option, even though -sel starts with - not --?

Comment: Option `-s` doesn't throw an error, but on my system, it seems to always get the contents of the `primary` selection, regardless of what argument you give it, even no argument at all. I dug through the documentation and even poked around the source code but couldn't find any info about it. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

More recent manpages (at least) say:

> Options can be abbreviated as long as they remain unambiguous. For example, it is possible to use **-d** or **-disp** instead of **-display**. However, **-v** couldn't be used because it is ambiguous (it could be short for **-verbose** or **-version**), so it would be interpreted as a filename.

That means that `-se` is sufficient for `-selection` but is not as good, mnemonically as `-sel`.