# Can a long option be shortened arbitrarily?

Tags: command-line, options

Is that a long option can be shortened arbitrarily part of GNU conventions for options, or some other conventions/standards, or just provided by some special C function?

For example, why do `python` and `awk` behave differently?

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
$ python --versio
Unknown option: --
usage: python [option] ... [-c cmd | -m mod | file | -] [arg] ...
Try `python -h' for more information.

$ awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
$ awk --versi
GNU Awk 4.1.3, API: 1.1 (GNU MPFR 3.1.4, GNU MP 6.1.0)
```

Thanks.

Comment: See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289191/abbreviated-long-options-on-the-command-line-of-xclip

Answer (score 6):

It's a feature of GNU libc, from [the getopt_long manpage](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/manpages-dev/getopt_long.3.en.html#getopt_long%28%29_and_getopt_long_only%28%29):

> Long option names may be abbreviated if the abbreviation is unique or is an exact match for some defined option.

Similarly, GNU libc's Argp interface also allows abbreviated options (though it's possible to reject them, if a program really cares).

As noted in [Abbreviated long options on the command line of xclip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/289191/abbreviated-long-options-on-the-command-line-of-xclip), xlib does the same thing, so `xclock -dig -bri` is the same as `xclock -digital -brief`.

I wouldn't recommend doing this in scripts: your `awk --ver` call be ambiguous if they added `awk --verbose`.

Python presumably has written its own argument parser, likely to be portable to systems which don't use glibc. And they can't just borrow the glibc one because they're not using the GNU GPL license.